# Xamarin Forms AD B2C MSAL sample using wrong tenant?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

The sample that Microsoft links to for the new MSAL preview (used by Xamarin Forms for connecting to AD B2C) looks to me like it is not connecting to the correct authority (tenant). Is this true? Have other people tried this?

Here is the sample: [active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)

When running their sample without changing their connection information (i.e. connecting to their fabrikamb2c tenant), it will pull up a login page in the Chrome browser. If I tell it to connect to a different account it pulls up my existing Microsoft accounts--so looking at a Microsoft AD tenant. Also, if I create my own AD B2C tenant and put that connection info into the sample it still tries to authenticate me against the Microsoft tenant rather than my new AD B2C tenant.

Are other people having problems with the login using the new MSAL preview library and mobile clients?

--This next information is being added on 5/29

I have three different projects that I've worked with. First, I worked directly with the Microsoft sample project (active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) as is--connecting to the fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com and using the configuration data that was delivered. Second, I took that project and I updated the configuration for my own newly-created ad b2c tenant. And third, I have my own project that was working using the previous version of MSAL and I updated it to use the new version.

I was having trouble running the sample project on Friday with the configuration as is. But it is running now and creating a local account for me. I wasn't able to do that for some reason. Anyway that looks good now.

Running the sample project, but updating the configuration information to authenticate against my newly-created ad b2c tenant, I'm having some troubles. Currently when I try to create a new account it is giving me this message:
[image]

If I login with an account that exists in my b2c tenant I get this:[image]

But after dismissing the exception, it has logged in and it gives me the login information.

Finally, in my own project I am getting an error message that makes it sound as if I'm the user is being authenticated against a different tenant. The user that I am trying to log in as does exist in the tenant. I had logged in with that user with the previous version of MSAL and I can see the user when I go into the tenant in AD B2C in Azure. Here is the error message--look at the details.[image]

EDIT: this section added 6/1/17

Here is the section of the App.cs that has my configuration. There were a couple other places that I had to make a configuration change, but the rest of the code is from the Microsoft sample mentioned above:

```
    public static string ClientID = "28a[edited this out]428";
    public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn";
    public static string PolicyEditProfile = "B2C_1_EditProfile";
    public static string PolicyResetPassword = "B2C_1_PasswordReset";

    //public static string[] Scopes = { "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/demoapi/demo.read" };
    public static string[] Scopes = { "Mail.read" };
    public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://[edited this out].azurewebsites.net/";

    public static string AuthorityBase = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[edited this out].onmicrosoft.com/"; //this is my resource name in my ad b2c settings
    public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";
    public static string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyEditProfile}";
    public static string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyResetPassword}";
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots to showcase the behavior and annotations explaining the differences in behavior you expect to see.

Comment: @Saca. Thanks for looking at this. I have edited the original post and added some screenshots of what is happening. I will be happy to give more information, but will be unavailable tomorrow before the evening. I will look at this post then.

Comment: It looks like the Authority is not being set up or being set up incorrectly for both of your attempts. Can you confirm that they're set up using: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<tenantName>/<policyName>`

Comment: @Saca. I added another edit showing the app.cs file with the configuration changes. Yes, in my comments earlier I was running it without the "tfp" part of the Authority URL. I had tried it that way since that is what is in the sample, but it didn't work and I didn't see that in any documentation so I removed it. I put it back again as you can see in the code, but the application just disappears when it gets to the AcquireTokenAsync call. You can see it open the browser and try to go to login.microsoftonline.com, but then it appears that it crashes and disappears and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Also, this is being run in an Android Emulator running Nexus 7, API 25.

Comment: Your scope is wrong, it needs to be in the format `https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/webapiuri/scope`

Comment: Thank you Saca. That is working. Can you tell me where to find documentation on that scope format?

Comment: @Steve Can you update with an answer on how you got around with the scope step? This will be much helpful.